# Streamwriter formatting

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I have to print out `count` variable (which is *non-negative*) in a special format:

1. The total length of the resulting string should be exactly 20 characters;
2. '0' characters, if necessary, should be added to the left of the string.

for instance:

```
  2   -> "00000000000000000002" // <- The length of each string is 20
  30  -> "00000000000000000030"
  123 -> "00000000000000000123"
```

What is the best way to achieve this in .Net?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `PadLeft`:

```
String value = "2";
String result = value.PadLeft(20, '0'); // <- 20 is desired string length, '0' - padding
```

Yet another possibility (in case you have integer value) is *formatting*:

```
int value = 2;
String result = value.ToString("D20");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think PadLeft is what you are looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string str = "2";
string str2 = "20";
char pad = '0';

Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(20, pad));  
Console.WriteLine(str2.PadLeft(20, pad));
```

That would produce a output of:
00000000000000000002
00000000000000000020

Answer (score 0):

If your original value is a string, your only option is to use PadLeft as Dmitry Bychenko answered, or create a custom format provider.

If on the other hand the original value is a number, you can use the standard format specifier `D` to format the number using padding, eg:

```
var s=String.Format("{0:D20}",5};
var s=String.Format("{0:D20}",50};
```

Zero-padding also works with the exponential `E` and the hexadecimal `X` specifier. MSDN contains a detailed description in [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
        string s = "00000000000000000000";
        string input = "20";
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            list.Add(Convert.ToString(item));
        }
        list.Add(input);

        int count = input.Length;

        list.RemoveRange(0, count);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            result.Append(item.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
```